# Seeing same item repeated multiple times on OS X 10.5.8 open with contextual menu

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, right-click

I dont know why I am getting same item repeated multiple times in the Open With contextual menu. I dont remember doing anything particular that might have caused the problem. Can anyone tell me how to get proper Open With menu back.
I am including a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution myself, just copy and paste this command in the terminal (credits to the original unknown author and google):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple copies of Firefox, MacVim, and Coda lying around on your disk?

OS X will look in places other than in /Applications when identifying what apps are available.

Comment: No I just ran a command in the terminal, see my post below